# Get Hibernate to delete association before entity

Tags: java, hibernate

The scenario is this. I have two entities, User and Post for a Twitter-like application. Consider the following

1. User Alice creates a post.
2. User Bob favorites the aforementioned post.
3. User Alice tries to delete the post.

When User Alice tries to delete the post, I get an error from Hibernate;

`ERROR: update or delete on table "posts" violates foreign key constraint "fk_jof9iwt9m3lfjxix5ejri4iv9" on table "favorite_posts"
  Detail: Key (id)=(16) is still referenced from table "favorite_posts".`

Code for my entities;

```
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<Post>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "favorite_posts")
    private Set<Post> favoritePosts = new HashSet<Post>();

    ...
}

@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post {
...
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
...
}
```

My alternatives as I see them;

1. Fetch all of the Users who have favorited a Post, and then clear all of them one by one.
2. Make the association bidirectional and then clear all of the favorites before deletion.

How can I get Hibernate to delete the association (= the corresponding row in favorite_posts) before trying to delete the entity?

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve this problem at the database level using `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the foreign key. It's the simpliest solution, and it doesn't bring extra complexity to the application layer.

However, this approach doesn't play well with your domain model, because your model treats `User` - `Post` relationships (both `post` and `favoritePosts`) as parts of a `User`. Therefore, you'll get constraint violation if you try to save a `User` while one of the `Post`s it's associated with is being removed.

This can be solved by moving ownership of `User` - `Post`s relationships away from `User`, for example, as follows:

- `User` <- `Post`: you probably would never need all `Post`s created by a `User` at once (without filtering or pagination). Therefore it makes no sense to map a relationship from `User` to `Post`, unidirectional relationship from `Post` to `User` is enough.
- `User` <- `FavoritePost` -> `Post`: moving "favorite post" relationship to its own entity allows it to have its own lifecycle. Now `FavoritePost` can silently disappear when associated `Post` is removed, and it won't create any inconsistency at the application level.